# UIImageView is not displayed after push navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I'm quite new to iOS development. I'm trying to create an iPad app where I need to display an image (here I used a.png). Image shows properly on the first view controller. Then, I navigate to other view using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>]
```

On the second viewcontroller, where I navigate to, I have put an UIImageView on the viewcontroller in the .xib using the interface builder. But, on running, when I navigate to the second viewcontroller, the imageview in the second viewcontroller is not displayed.

That is, on any normal viewcontroller uiimageview is working perfectly, but after navigation (i.e. self.navigationController pushViewController), the uiimageview isn't displayed in the next viewcontroller.

I tried debugging. After running the flow goes to the viewDidLoad of the second viewcontroller. I even tried to alloc the UIImageView in the viewDidLoad, on running the control goes to alloc of UIImageView, and even is allocated properly (that is not nil). But still, I'm not sure why image is not visible.Earlier I figured maybe it is not loading and on appear it is nil, but on debugging I found it is not nil.

I'm stumped. Can't figure out what I may be missing.

Suggestions please. I need help to figure out what all may be the cause of UIImageView image not being displayed.

Comment: check IBOutlet connection?

Comment: Paste your code what you had tried ?

Comment: `code`    PhotoGalleryViewController *photoGalleryViewController = [[PhotoGalleryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoGalleryViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoGalleryViewController animated:YES];

Comment: remove imageview allocation in photoGalleryViewController viewDidLoad method.

Comment: in the photoGalleryViewController, I have assigned the image to uiimageview in the xib

Comment: i haven't written code to allocate imageview in the viedDidLoad or viewWillAppear. Though, I tried keeping imageview alloc code in didLoad and/or willAppear, but removed from both places. The imageview image is not displayed in any of the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your `UIImageView` is Properly Connected to `file's Owner` or Not ??

- create object of `UIImageView` in `.h file`
- And Set @property and @synthesize of `UIImageView`
- And Then After Check Your `Image` (*Which put on `UIImageView`*) Has Valid Name.

**EDITE:**

Try To Add `UIImageView` Programmatically

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 320, 375)] ; // set Frame as you need
    [myImageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MYImage.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview: myImageView];
}
```

Comment: I have already created  an object in .h file, have set the Set property and synthesize, and confirmed the IBOutlet connection. The UIImageView is properly connected to file's owner. I have assigned image to the UIImageView on the .xib using the Interface Builder. I've used the same image on the previous viewcontroller and it is working fine there.

Comment: self.yourImagViewObj.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfYourImage"]; try with this code

Comment: Had tried that too. Didn't work. I had tried this in viewDidLoad, didn't work. tried in viewWillAppear, didn't work. I also tried [self.yourImagViewObj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfYourImage"]]. even that didn't work. I fear there may be something that goes wrong when I navigate by pushViewController

Comment: @Monty- i am sure that mistake in UIImageView...i will put UIImageView progametticaly add it :)

Comment: this works! thanks! I had tried this but had missed the addSubView. Just had to add the addSubView code and it worked. Though this works for now, I still want to know why it didn't work if I drag-and-dropped UIImageView in xib, assigned an image to it, properly connected it to file's owner with proper IBOutlet conection.

Comment: @Monty-good i glad to help you..welcome, and close this question by accept answer it it is helpful for u :)

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer. Though for the logic I wanted to implement I didn't want it to be in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, but anyways I'll twist the logic a bit. Though this works for now, I still, for hungry curiosity, want to know why it didn't work if I drag-and-dropped UIImageView in xib, assigned an image to it, properly connected it to file's owner with proper IBOutlet conection.

Comment: Also, what bugs me is that it works totally fine in the first viewController, with same image and similarly placed UIImageView, but after [self.navigator pushViewController:secondViewController] in the secondViewController I am forced to take extra measures as you mentioned. What is it that changes??